# CF/SQL converting datetime to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion and SQL Server. I am trying to convert the `Due_Date` into MM/DD/YYYY.

The database is set up like this and unfortunately I am not able to make any alterations to it.[image].

I am making a call like so:

```
<cffunction name="displayTable" access="public" returntype="query">
    <cfquery name="processTable">
        SELECT id, Date_Due, Date_Complete, Item_Count
        FROM dbo.Dealer_Track_Work      
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn processTable>
</cffunction>
```

I have tried many combinations of something similar to this:

```
<cffunction name="displayTable" access="public" returntype="query">
    <cfquery name="processTable">
        SELECT id, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, Date_Due, 120), Date_Complete, Item_Count
        FROM dbo.Dealer_Track_Work      
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn processTable>
</cffunction>
```

Can anyone spot where I may be going wrong? I was thinking because the database is set up as datetime and this is converting to varchar but I still cannot come up with the correct combination. (And am not allowed to change the table) Any assistance in getting my output to read MM/DD/YYYY would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would run your query like below. Don't forget to var scope your `processTable` variable

```
<cffunction name="displayTable" access="public" returntype="query">
  <cfset var processTable = ''>
  <cfquery name="processTable">
    SELECT id, Date_Due, Date_Complete, Item_Count
    FROM dbo.Dealer_Track_Work      
  </cfquery>
  <cfreturn processTable>
</cffunction>
```

and then perform the format on the ColdFusion side

```
#dateFormat(processTable.Date_Due, 'mm/dd/yyyy')#
```

Comment: why do you do this line? <cfset var processTable = ''>

Comment: That ensures the variable is private to the current function context and will not be available outside the function.

Comment: @MattBusche As of CF 9, you can just do name="local.processTable" to keep the variable scoped as local to the function (Var scoped).

Answer (score 3):

Should not you be using 101?

```
<cffunction name="displayTable" access="public" returntype="query">
  <cfquery name="processTable">
    SELECT id, CONVERT(CHAR(10), Date_Due, 101), Date_Complete, Item_Count
    FROM dbo.Dealer_Track_Work      
  </cfquery>
  <cfreturn processTable>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: (Edit) Yes, format 101 also works.  For a full list of formats see [CAST and CONVERT in the BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). That said, it is typically preferable to leave the values as datetime objects as long as possible in case you need to do any date math on the objects.  Do the formatting in CF, only when needed.  Also, for CF - do not forget to `var/local` scope the query name to avoid possible threading issue.

Comment: Agreed. Leave the DB to do data processing; it's CF's job to do the "last mile" output formatting.